# Reading registry keys using WMI

Tags: c#, registry, wmi

I am trying to read the registry key by using WMI. I have tried with following code but i am unable to get the registry key value.

Can anyone help me regarding this problem.

```
ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
System.Management.ManagementScope scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"\\" +hostname + @"\root\cimv2", oConn);

scope.Connect();
ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\.NETFramework";
inParams["sValueName"] = "InstallRoot";


ManagementBaseObject outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);

if (outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
{
 output = outParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();

}
```

Note: i want to read the registry keys by using WMI only.

Comment: What result do you get? Exception/Error, null value or unexpected value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the value of the [`hDefKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (hive) parameter and remove the hive from the `sSubKeyName` parameter.

```
inParams["hDefKey"] =0x80000002;// HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\.NETFramework";
```